# Solving the system: $x_1d_1\theta=...=x_kd_k\theta=(1-x_{k+1})^2d_{k+1}=...=(1-x_{n})^2d_{n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, numerical-methods

Let 
$$Q=\frac{a_1d_1x_1+...+a_nd_nx_n}{\frac{a_1}{1-x_1}+...+\frac{a_n}{1-x_n}}$$

where $(x_1,..,x_n)\in (0,1)^n$ and $d_i$ and $a_i$ are positive constants, with $$a_1+...+a_n=1.$$ There is no restriction on $d_i$s, they are just positive constants.

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$$x_1d_1\theta=...=x_kd_k\theta=(1-x_{k+1})^2d_{k+1}=...=(1-x_{n})^2d_{n}=Q$$

where $0<\theta<1$ and  $1≤k<n$.

I can simulate this system and numerically pin down the solution, call it $(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)\in(0,1)^n$, but just I could not characterize it analytically.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to reduce the systems of equations to a single variable equation, $x_1$. Then, all the remaining variables can be solved by the equalities to $Q$.

From the initial system, note:
$$Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{a_i}{1-x_i}} \right)=\sum_{p=1}^n{a_px_pd_p}=\sum_{p=1}^k{a_px_pd_p} + \sum_{q=k+1}^n{a_qx_qd_q}$$
For the first $k$ terms on the $r.h.s$, observe $\frac{Q}{\theta}=a_px_p=a_1x_1$, and so
$$Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{a_i}{1-x_i}} \right)=a_1x_1\sum_{p=1}^k{d_p} + \sum_{q=k+1}^n{a_qx_qd_q}$$

Similarly, break the $l.h.s$ into the first $k$ terms and the remaining terms:
$$Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{a_i}{1-x_i}} \right)=Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_i}{1-x_i}} \right)+Q\left( \sum_{j=k+1}^n {\frac{a_j}{1-x_j}} \right)$$

Again, the first $k$ terms involving $x_i$ can be reduced to an expression of $x_1$ by similar substitution.
$$Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_i}{1-x_i}} \right)=Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_i}{1-\frac{x_1d_1}{d_i}}} \right)=Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_id_i}{d_i-x_1d_1}} \right)$$

For the last $n-k$ terms, note that $Q=(1-x_j^2)d_j$, and thus:
$$Q\left( \sum_{j=k+1}^n {\frac{a_j}{1-x_j}} \right) = \sum_{j=k+1}^n a_j(1+x_j)d_j$$

Substituting into the original equation:
$$Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_id_i}{d_i-x_1d_1}} \right)+\sum_{j=k+1}^n a_j(1+x_j)d_j=a_1x_1\sum_{p=1}^k{d_p} + \sum_{q=k+1}^n{a_qx_qd_q}$$

Note we can eliminate the $a_qx_qd_q$ terms on both sides. Then, we arrive at:
$$\sum_{j=k+1}^n a_jd_j=a_1x_1\sum_{p=1}^k{d_p}-Q\left( \sum_{i=1}^k {\frac{a_id_i}{d_i-x_1d_1}} \right)$$

This becomes a $(k+1)$-order polynomial of $x_1$ the solution of which would have to be generally obtained numerically.